# Python: Firefoxdriver selenium error (filenotfound)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe') #error line
```

I got an exception from last line (where the driver is declared):

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmp6blxsv\\webdriver-py-profilecopy\\user.js'
```

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of Selenium WebDriver, since the `executable_path` argument has been removed in recent versions. Try upgrading first.

Comment: @Бармар but the firefox_profile argument was also removed in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, but I had to piece together the solutions.

1. Update selenium:
   `python -m pip install selenium -U`
2. Download the new geckodriver (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases /)
3. Updated code (comparing old and new):

old:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
options=Options()
profile = FirefoxProfile()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
```

new:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
profile = FirefoxProfile()
options.profile = profile
service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')

options.add_argument("-headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=service )
```